# multi-thread OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, spring-boot, thread-safety

I have multiple threads that read in one table. 
Each thread want to read a value from the table and then change the state from `used = ‘N’` to `used = ‘Y’`;

```
Value = `Select min(myColumn) where used =’N’`
```

I put my method as synchronized but it happens that multiple threads read the same value and when the second try to update used to ‘Y’ he had the `*OptimisticLockException*`. And I have a performance problem when many threads due to `*OptimisticLockException*`.
The `SKIP_LOCK` solution is not applicable to my case.

Have you any idea please how can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Spring Boot, but using plain JPA, when you do a query, you can set the LockMode.

Something like this:

`query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`

This way, the SQL generated uses the database features (normally it means that it appends a "for update" to the SQL query), to do a lock on the selected data, to prevent other clients from reading it till the transaction ends.

If you use this type of lock there is no need to use any synchronization at the method level, because the concurrency will be controlled at the database level.

This article explains in more detail using pessimistic locking in JPA: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking

Comment: Thank you four our response, the pessimistic lock will not lock all rows of table > because of the function min(myColumn) ?  and then blockm all the other threads ?

Comment: select mycolumn where mycolumn = (select min(myColumn) where used =’N’) for update?

Comment: I mean, with that request, instead of the original, it will only block a row

Comment: My request right now is like that, but I have multiple OptimisticLockException when several threads

Comment: `"select mycol from myBeanTable join fetch myBeanTable.myBeanRef where "
                        + " myBeanTable.mycol= (select min(i.myCol) from myBeanTable i where i.myBeanRef.invoiceNumberStatusId = 0"`

Comment: `"select mycol from myBeanTable join fetch myBeanTable.myBeanRef where "
                        + " myBeanTable.mycol= (select min(i.myCol) from myBeanTable i where i.myBeanRef.invoiceNumberStatusId = 0"`

Comment: I've expanded the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Could you try it?